# How to join two different git repositories into one with two branches?

Tags: git

I want to join two different git repositories into one repository with two branches. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a new repository, then add both of these repositories as remotes:

```
git remote add origin1 ...
git remote add origin2 ...
```

Fetch from both:

```
git fetch origin1
git fetch origin2
```

Create a local branch to track a branch of each remote (assuming the master):

```
git branch branch1 origin1/master
git branch branch2 origin2/master
```